# Why this is not an array?

Tags: php

```
Entity {#848 ▼
  #attributes: array:3 [▼
    0 => array:4 [▶]
    1 => array:4 [▶]
    2 => array:4 [▶]
  ]
}

is_array($dump) // False
is_array($dump[0]) // True
```

Why the first result is false?

How can i handle this as an array?

Comment: Please post the output of: `var_dump($yourArray);`

Comment: is_object($dump) http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php

Comment: @xDk I think you can delete this question here, since it will not serve anyone